# AirPods not showing the sub BlueTooth menu

Tags: airpods

I have an issue...my airpods behave weird...they won’t show me the sub bluetooth menu...help please.I’m on IOS 12.14.I have an Iphone 8 plus.i’ve tried resetting the airpods and removing the connection with my aipods...to no Avail

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, perform a full restart (Settings - General - Shut Down - Power Off slider). Turn on, then goto  Settings - Bluetooth menu.

With my AirPods in the charging case with lid closed, it says disconnected. I open the case, and tap the Airpods to get them to connect. Mine says Connected (for you "Connecté" or similar).

I then see the Airpods information pop-up box with charging levels. I can click the information (i) button next to the AirPods to get to the sub-menu.

After performing these steps, do you see the sub-menu? If not, you may want to make an appointment at the Apple Store.

This link may be helpful as well:
https://www.imore.com/how-to-troubleshoot-reset-airpods

Hope this helps.